# SVN renaming files to uppercase after merge

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, svn, tortoisesvn

some background: I work on Windows 10 and have a C# project that contains some `.cs` files like `Foo.cs`, which are mostly (but not exclusively) auto-generated from database tables by the Entity Framework. Additionally I use SVN (with TortoiseSVN) for version control.

So recently, after merging another branch, I noticed that some files went "missing". After checking them in the explorer, I noticed that they were renamed to entirely uppercase, e.g. `FOO.CS`, even though they were not renamed just modified in the branch I merged. Even stranger: When I tried to rename `FOO.CS` back to `Foo.cs` manually through the Windows Explorer, the file name instantly changed back to `FOO.CS`. Which files were renamed seemed random to me and I don't see anything that makes the renamed files different to any of the other files.

I am really clueless to what is happening here and this problem keeps re-emerging constantly in my Entity Framework project forcing me to manually copy changes to my branch (yuck!). At the moment I suspect SVN or TortoiseSVN to be the culprits here, but I might be wrong (maybe Visual Studio is messing with my file names, or it could be me doing something stupid?).

I couldn't find any threads about my problem, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that Subversion wasn't the true culprit. The real problem was my local repository folder which was stored on a FAT32 drive. Apparently FAT32 does not distinguish between upper- and lowercase characters for file names and a newly created file named `TEST.TXT` shows the same behaviour as the `FOO.CS` I described in my question.

So using another file system like NTFS should solve my problem.